# How to use a dynamic identifier to check for values of UI elements?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-ui-testing

I am getting started with UI testing with Xcode and I am trying to check for the value of a UITextField.
I can easily do this by

```
XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts[@"value of string"].exists);
```

I do, however, want to do the very same thing with dynamic content. Ideally, I would need something like

```
NSString* requiredValue = "computed string";
XCTAssertTrue(app.staticTexts[requiredValue].exists);
```

How can I implement this? I would greatly appreciated any hint or link to good resources that might answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the label via its `accessibilityIdentifier` instead of its content/value.

First set the identifier in your production code. This will also only show up during testing, not even for users with accessibility enabled.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.accessibilityIdentifier = @"Username";
label.text = @"can be anything"; // just to prove the point
```

Then in your tests you can reference it.

```
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts[@"Username"].exists);
```

Here are a few references I've written for help with UI Testing:

- [UI Testing in Xcode 7](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-xcode-7/)
- [UI Testing Cheat Sheet and Examples](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/)
- [XCTest Reference](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/)

Comment: That's pretty cool! How can I then access the text from the `XCUIElementQuery`?

Comment: @SebastianHojas:
`XCTAssertEqual(app.staticTexts[@"Username"].label, @"can be anything");`

Comment: Ah perfect, that's what I was exactly looking for. Thanks!